# Why doesn't work my Ironpython program for data transfer via MQTT?

Tags: python, wpf, mqtt, ironpython, paho

I program in Ironpython, and have the following problem:

I am not shown an error, but when I press run, my window window does not start and the message "The program" [12692] ipyw32.exe "was terminated with code 1 (0x1)."

My code is:

```
from System.Windows import Application, Window

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

class MyWindow(Window):
   def __init__(self):
       wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'WpfApplication2.xaml')

       client = mqtt.Client()
       client.on_connect = on_connect
       client.on_message = on_message

       client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883, 60)

       client.loop_forever()

   def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
       print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

   def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
       print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

       if msg.payload == "Hello":
           print("Received message #1, do something")

       if msg.payload == "World!":
            print("Received message #2, do something else")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

can someone help me or know where my mistake is?

Answer (score 0):

Because `client.loop_forever()` never returns so the `__init__()` function will never return.

You probably need to call `client.loop_start()` to run the MQTT client loop on a separate thread.